# How to conditionally render 3 different lists in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

As you can see from the code, at first I want all the todos to be shown, then toggle between all, active and completed todos. I have made the arrays for the active and completed todos, but I'm not quite sure how to implement the switching between those lists. For example, how can I render only active todos instead of the all the todos, etc.?

```
return (
    <div className='card'>
      <TodoForm addTodo={addTodo} />
      <div className='list-group'>
              {
            todos.map((item, index) =>
              item.isEditing ? <TodoEditForm item={item} key={index} editTask={editTask} /> :
                <Todo item={item} key={index}
                  toggleCompleted={toggleCompleted}
                  removeTodo={removeTodo}
                  toggleEdit={toggleEdit} />
            )
              }

          {
            bool ? 
            <div>
              Active
            </div> 
            :
            <div>
              Completed
            </div>
          }
      </div>
      <div className='toggle-todos-wrapper'>
        <button className="toggle-todos-button btn btn-light">All</button>
        <button className="toggle-todos-button btn btn-light">Active</button>
        <button className="toggle-todos-button btn btn-light">Completed</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TodoWrapper
```

I tried using the ternary operator to switch between the active and completed todos, but the all todos remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the code snippet is partial, I am not sure how are you exactly `making` the arrays for `active` and `completed` *todos*. Therefore, I will assume that you have something like this in your code:

```
   /*Existing imports*/       
   const allTodos = [...allTodos]; //Array containing all Todos
   const activeTodos = [...activeTodos]; //Array containing all 'active' Todos
   const completedTodos = [...completedTodos]; //Array containing all 'completed' Todos    
   function TodoWrapper({...props}){
        /*Existing code*/
        return(
      /*Your return logic posted above*/
    )
   }
```

Now either you are getting arrays from props or generating dynamically the following approach should work the same. To address the conditional rendering, you might need to change your existing code a bit. First of all instead of mapping over the `todos` array inside return `JSX`, move that logic to a re-usable function. Secondly, your ternary operator can work but currently you are using a `bool` variable, which I assume is a boolean variable, to determine the kind of `todos` to render. If you want to show 3 different kinds of *Todos*, then you shall change the `bool` to local state. And might set its type to an `enum` or `constant` array. But I will use strings for simplicity.

The following changes shall get your code to conditionally toggle between the 3 types of *Todos* rendering:

```
/*Existing imports*/       
   const allTodos = [...allTodos]; //Array containing all Todos
   const activeTodos = [...activeTodos]; //Array containing all 'active' Todos
   const completedTodos = [...completedTodos]; //Array containing all 'completed' Todos    
   function TodoWrapper({...props}){
        /*Existing code*/
        const [todoType,setTodoType] = useState('all'); //You can use Enum or constants as it is going to have only one of the three different values at any time
        const handleTodoTypeChange = (type) => () => {
          setTodoType(tpye); // type can either be 'all', 'active', or 'completed'
        };
        const renderTodos = () => {
         let filteredTodos = allTodos;
         if(todoType === "active") filteredTodos = activeTodos;
         else if(todoType === "completed") filteredTodos = completedTodos;
         const list =filteredTodos.map((item, index) =>
              item.isEditing ? <TodoEditForm item={item} key={index} editTask={editTask} /> :
                <Todo item={item} key={index}
                  toggleCompleted={toggleCompleted}
                  removeTodo={removeTodo}
                  toggleEdit={toggleEdit} />
            );
         return list;
        }
        return (
            <div className='card'>
              <TodoForm addTodo={addTodo} />
              <div className='list-group'>
              {
                renderTodos() 
              }
              </div>
              <div className='toggle-todos-wrapper'>
                <button className="toggle-todos-button btn btn-light" onClick={handleTodoTypeChange("all")}>All</button>
                <button className="toggle-todos-button btn btn-light" onClick={handleTodoTypeChange("active")}>Active</button>
                <button className="toggle-todos-button btn btn-light" onClick={handleTodoTypeChange("completed")}>Completed</button>
              </div>
        </div>
      )
}
export default TodoWrapper
```

I have removed the ternary logic from your existing code as it is being handled inside the newly created `renderTodos` function.

Comment: It works, when i click on the edit/remove button when im in any list it works but it doesnt show when i remove it or try to edit it.I think its because im not updating any state so it doesnt rerender when i click it? I tried adding the set functions for completed/active todos state in every method but it seems repetitive. Maybe there is another shorter way of doing it im not aware of.

Comment: For example `   const removeTodo = (id) => {
    setTodos(todos.filter(item => item.id !== id))
    setcompletedTodos(completedTodos.filter(item => item.id !== id))
    setactiveTodos(activeTodos.filter(item => item.id !== id))
  }`

Comment: Well in that case, you may want to change the renderTodos method from above a bit. The method in the answer assumes you already have 3 different arrays, for each category. But yes this would need to have repetitive logic to update/remove todos. You may only store one state for 'all' todos, and in renderTodos method dynamically filter based on the category selected.

Comment: Following would be the modified version of renderTodos method:
const renderTodos = () => {
         let filteredTodos = allTodos;
         if(todoType === "active") filteredTodos = allTodos.filter(item => item.isActive);
         else if(todoType === "completed") filteredTodos = allTodos.filter(item => item.isCompleted);
         //Rest remains the same
        }

Comment: Note that above refactoring assumes you have all todos in a state variable called 'allTodos'. And with that now you can have the same old update/remove methods which would simply filter out 'allTodos' and UI shall reflect the changes.

Comment: Well i fixed this using useEffect, included the setStates for active/completed todos there and added allTodos array as a dependancy.It works as far as i can tell.

Comment: Good to know that you got it to working.

Answer (score 0):

You may proceed by introducing a new `state` variable that acts as a flag telling which category (all, completed or active) is being selected.

That variable can therefore be used to filter the todos on the fly to display those in the category being selected or all of them when **All** button is selected.

Below a code snippet that demponstrates the aforementioned attempt:

```js
function ToDoList({ todos }) {
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("all"),
    handleClick = e => setCategory(e.target.dataset.completed),
    filtered = category === "all" ? todos : todos.filter(t => t.completed == +category);
  
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="list-group">
        {filtered.map(({ text, completed }) => <li>{`${text}: ${completed ? 'Done' : 'Active'}`}</li>)}
      </div>
      <div className="toggle-todos-wrapper">
        <button
          className="toggle-todos-button btn btn-light"
          onClick={handleClick}
          data-completed="all"
        >All
        </button>
        <button
          className="toggle-todos-button btn btn-light"
          onClick={handleClick}
          data-completed="0"
        >Active
        </button>
        <button
          className="toggle-todos-button btn btn-light"
          onClick={handleClick}
          data-completed="1"
        >Completed
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here's a live demo on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Thabet_Sakhraoui/full/YzgOMzP).

I hope you get the idea and I strongly advise you to customize it the way you see fit and build upon it based on your requirements. Hope you find that attempt helpful.

Finally, there might be some tweaks that can be applied as improvements and memorizing the filtering callback between re-renders is one of them especially when the `todos` set is getting larger. I recommend visiting the [Docs](https://react.dev/) to learn more about those potential tweaks.

Please feel free to ask further questions about the suggested solution and I'll gladly help you out.